# How to define (in Java) which cryptographic protocol (SSL or TLS) does a server use?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-commons-httpclient

I have Client Application, which use apache-commons-httpclient 2.0 that I need to connect to different servers. 
As a cryptographic protocols I use:

```
protocols = new String[]{"SSLv3", "SSLv2Hello", "TLSv1"};
((SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
```

Generally, it works fine, but with some servers the following happens:

```
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
main, SEND SSLv3 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 22
0000: 02 0A 7B FA 57 7E 6E B7   56 4C 8A 2F 7F 1F BC 9F  ....W.n.VL./....
0010: A6 80 57 12 0B EE                                  ..W...
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Alert, length = 22
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
```

If I remove TLSv1 from the protocols list, it'll works fine with this server and I'll get expected 200 Status.
Thereby, I have this question - how to define beforehand which protocol (SSL or TLS) and protocol version does server support?

Or maybe there is other way to resolve this problem?

Comment: I recall that TLSv1.0 has a security issues - I'd think it might be rejected because of that... I'd try with "TLSv1.2" instead.

Comment: @ppeterka66, it's unlikely that a server that supports SSLv3 but not TLSv1 will support TLSv1.2. TLSv1.2 support is unfortunately not very widespread yet.

Comment: Try the same server without changing the enabled protocols at all.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found out how to get enabled server protocols:

```
Socket socket = sSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
((SSLSocket) socket).getEnabledProtocols();
```

But it doesn't help, 'cause it gives me:

```
SSLv2Hello
SSLv3
TLSv1
```

It means that the server should support TLSv1. So the problem is somewhere else.